# Matrix file to dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, matrix

I have a file `matrix.txt` that contains :

```
   A  B  C
A  1  2  3
B  4  5  6
C  7  8  9
```

I want to read the content of the file and store it in a dictionary as following :

```
{('A', 'A') : 1, ('A', 'B') : 2, ('A', 'C') : 3,
 ('B', 'A') : 4, ('B', 'B') : 5, ('B', 'C') : 6,
 ('C', 'A') : 7, ('C', 'B') : 8, ('C', 'C') : 9}
```

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You should really be including code you've tried, and why it results in an output that is not what you expect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks the SE community to provide code, without having cited any problem or attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python3 function will yield all matrix items with it's indices, compatible with `dict` constructor:

```
def read_mx_cells(file, parse_cell = lambda x:x):
  rows = (line.rstrip().split() for line in file)
  header = next(rows)
  for row in rows:
    row_id = row[0]
    for col_id,cell in zip(header, row[1:]):
      yield ((row_id, col_id), parse_cell(cell))

with open('matrix.txt') as f:
  for x in read_mx_cells(f, int):
    print(x)
# ('A','A'),1
# ('A','B'),2
# ('A','C'),3 ...

with open('matrix.txt') as f:
  print(dict(read_mx_cells(f, int)))
# { ('A','A'): 1, ('A','B'): 2, ('A','C'): 3 ... } 
# Note that python dicts dont retain item order
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`  to create your keys, using the file header and the first column after transposing to create the keys, then just zip transforming the remaining rows back to their original state and creating a single iterable of the split substrings.  To maintain order we also need to use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import izip,  product, imap, chain

with open("matrix.txt") as f:
    head, zipped = next(f).split(), izip(*imap(str.split, f))
    cols = next(zipped)
    od = OrderedDict(zip(product(head, cols), chain.from_iterable(izip(*zipped))))
```

Output:

```
  OrderedDict([(('A', 'A'), '1'), (('A', 'B'), '2'), (('A', 'C'), '3'),
  (('B', 'A'), '4'), (('B', 'B'), '5'), (('B', 'C'), '6'), (('C', 'A'), '7'),
  (('C', 'B'), '8'), (('C', 'C'), '9')])
```

For python3 just use `map` and `zip`.

Or without transposing and using the csv lib:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import izip,repeat
import csv

with open("matrix.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=1)
    head = repeat(next(r))
    od = OrderedDict((((row[0], k), v) for row in r 
                     for k, v in izip(next(head), row[1:])))
```

output will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` makes it pretty neat.

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Approach 1**

```
df = pd.read_table('matrix.txt', sep='  ')
>>> df
   A  B  C
A  1  2  3
B  4  5  6
C  7  8  9

d = df.to_dict()
>>> d
{'A': {'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 7},
 'B': {'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 8},
 'C': {'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}}

new_d = {}
{new_d.update(g) for g in [{(r,c):v for r,v in v1.iteritems()} for c,v1 in d.iteritems()]}

>>> new_d
{('A', 'A'): 1,
 ('A', 'B'): 2,
 ('A', 'C'): 3,
 ('B', 'A'): 4,
 ('B', 'B'): 5,
 ('B', 'C'): 6,
 ('C', 'A'): 7,
 ('C', 'B'): 8,
 ('C', 'C'): 9}
```

**Approach 2**

```
df = pd.read_table('matrix.txt', sep='  ')
>>> df
   A  B  C
A  1  2  3
B  4  5  6
C  7  8  9

new_d = {}
for r, v in df.iterrows():
    for c, v1 in v.iteritems():
        new_d.update({(r,c): v1})

>>> new_d
{('A', 'A'): 1,
 ('A', 'B'): 2,
 ('A', 'C'): 3,
 ('B', 'A'): 4,
 ('B', 'B'): 5,
 ('B', 'C'): 6,
 ('C', 'A'): 7,
 ('C', 'B'): 8,
 ('C', 'C'): 9}
```